# Zend Framework action helpers

Tags: php, zend-framework, action, helper

I'm pretty much newbie in Zend Framework action helpers and I am trying to use them with no success (I read a bunch of posts about action helpers, including http://devzone.zend.com/article/3350 and found no solution in like 8 hours). I used Zend Tool to setup my project and the name of the helper is Action_Helper_Common. No matter what I do, I get following error "Fatal error: Class 'Action_Helper_Common' not found". Currently, I have things set up like this:

- zf version: 1.11.3
- helper name: Action_Helper_Common
- helpers location:
  /application/controllers/helpers/Common.php

In Bootstrap.php i have following function:

```
    protected function _initActionHelpers() {
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers/helpers', 'Action_Helper');
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(
        new Action_Helper_Common(null, $session)
    );
}
```

I also tried this without success (it was defined in Bootstrap.php before _initActionHelpers):

```
protected function _initAutoloader() {
    $moduleLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => '', 
        'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers/helpers'));
    return $moduleLoader;
}
```

So what am I doing wrong?!?! PLZ help, I am desperate and about to give up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got error because you haven't setup autoloader for Action_Helper_*

[Resource autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html)

Helper broker uses plugin loader to load helpers based on paths and prefixes you specified to it. That is why ::getHelper() can find your helper

Comment: Thanks man! That's just what I wanted, it works now by setting autoloader namespace to 'Action' with basePath "APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers/helpers'" and specifying resourceType Helper.

Comment: `if($classname = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getPluginLoader()->load('Common')) { $helper = new $classname()}`
This is other way to load your helper

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to do (so remove it)

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(
        new Action_Helper_Common(null, $session)
    ); ,
```

since you already did

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers/helpers', 'Action_Helper');
```

when you will do

```
$myhelper = $this->getHelper('Common');
```

in your controller zf will lookinto directory /controllers/helpers/ for class name Action_Helper_Common and create an instance for you and return it.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the following line didn't work for me as well:

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper( new Action_Helper_Common() );
```

I just keep getting a 'Class not found' error each time I'm creating a new helper object explicitly.

This is what works for me:

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getHelper('Common');
```

In this case, new `Action_Helper_Common` object gets created and is registered with `Helper Broker`.

Not sure though if it works for you, since you have a parameterized constructor.